# Firebase Error : Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 14:0-36

Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package C:\Users\isteb\Desktop\codeBase\ReactJS\Project\fb-messenger-clone\messenger\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in C:\Users\isteb\Desktop\codeBase\ReactJS\Project\fb-messenger-clone\messenger\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\isteb\Desktop\codeBase\ReactJS\Project\fb-messenger-clone\messenger\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

Anyone Please help me to debug this.

I am pushing this code to my github account you can check.

Comment: https://github.com/istebsharul/Messenger-Clone.git

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

const firebaseConfig = {


your fire base congig code
  };


export const fireBase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

*You have to import firebase like this way import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';*